# how to return a Json array after serializing in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have an Action Method that i am using to return GeoJson data using GeoJson.Net. The Action Method is shown below:

```
public ActionResult GetWorldGeometry()
{
    var worldgeo = (from w in _bdEntities.worlds1 select w);
    foreach (var w in  worldgeo )
    {
        var world = SqlGeometry.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars(w.geom.AsText()), 4326);
        var worldGeometry = world.ToGeoJSONGeometry();
        var worldFeatureProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"Name", w.NAME},
            {"Population(05)", w.POP2005},
            {"Region", w.REGION},
            {"ISO2", w.ISO2},
            {"ISO3", w.ISO3},
            {"Area", w.AREA}
        };
        var feature = new Feature(worldGeometry, worldFeatureProperties);

        var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(feature, Formatting.Indented,
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
            });

        return Content(serializedData, "application/json");
    } 
    return null;
}
```

On my view, i want to plot this GeoJson to Leaflet or OpenLayers but i am currently testing the output of the Action method using the code below:

```
        <div>
           <p>
             <span id="add_here"></span>
           </p>
         </div>

         @section scripts
           {
            <script>
              $.ajax({
                  url: '@Url.Action("GetJsonResult", "Home")',
                  dataType: "json", 
                  type: "GET", 
                  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                  cache: false, 
                  data: {}, 
                  traditional: true,
                  success: function(data) {
                  var reslen = data.length;
                  alert(reslen);
                  var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                  alert(result);
                  $('#add_here').text(result);
                       },
                  error: function(xhr) {
                  alert('error');
                       }
                    });
                </script>
               }
```

Instead of getting an array of data, i am jus getting the first result.On alerting the result length, it says "Undefined". How can i get all the data that has been returned by the query in the Action method in my view? Below is a snippet of the single result that is returned and the alert message:
[Output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI6ol.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you what , i hope it will work didnt test it out.

```
    public class WorldFeatureProperties
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Population05 { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string ISO2 { get; set; }
        public string ISO3 { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string WorldGeometry { get; set; }
    }


    public ActionResult GetWorldGeometry()
    {
        var worldgeo = (from w in _bdEntities.worlds1 select w);

        var retval = new List<WorldFeatureProperties>();



        foreach (var w in worldgeo)
        {

            var currentLocation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorldFeatureProperties>(w);

            currentLocation.WorldGeometry = WorldGeometry.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars(w.geom.AsText()), 4326).ToGeoJSONGeometry();

            retval.Add(currentLocation);
       }

        var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retval, Formatting.Indented,
              new JsonSerializerSettings
              {
                  ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                  NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
              });
        return Json(serializedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: The code is giving an error, the first two lines inside the foreach loop, but working on the idea

Comment: as i said i didnt try code block , but you have idea now you will do it well

Comment: Yah, i gues i am so close now, check out the edit  but i am now getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error, Ajax cant get anything to laert or display